# How do I remove the border between rows in a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I have an image that I have broken up so when you hover over certain parts that certain quote bubble will get bigger and easier to read. Since I have broken up the image, I have put the pieces into a table. I have managed to get rid of the border between the 2 columns but I cannot figure out how to get rid of the border between the rows. I have tried `border=0, cellspacing=0, cellpadding=0, border=none` on the `<td>` and `<tr>` tags and it does not work.
Could someone please help me figure out how to get rid of these white lines between the rows of my table so my image fits together?

```css
/* Quote Image and Table */
table { 
 border: none;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}

#picture {
 width:100%; 
 height: auto;
}

#picture a.small, #picture a.small:visited { 
 display:block; 
 width:100%; 
 height:auto; 
 text-decoration:none; 
 background:#ffffff; 
 top:0; 
 left:0; 
 border:0;
}

#picture a img {
 border:0;
}

#picture a.small:hover {
 text-decoration:none; 
 background-color:#000000; 
 color:#000000;
}

#picture a .large {
 display:block; 
 position:absolute; 
 width:0; 
 height:0; 
 border:0; 
 top:0; 
 left:0;
}

#picture a.small:hover .large {
 display:block; 
 position:absolute; 
 top: 90px; 
 left:150px; 
 width:80%; 
 height:auto; 
}
/* Quote Image and Table */
```

```html
<div id="picture">
<center>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr style="border:0;">
    <td style="border:0;"><a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="images/quote1.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="images/quote1.png" title="large image" /></a></td>
    <td style="border:0;"><a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="images/quote2.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="images/quote2.png" title="large image" /></a></td> 
  </tr>
  
  <tr style="border:0;">
    <td style="border:0;"><a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="images/quote3.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="images/quote3.png" title="large image" /></a></td>
    <td style="border:0;"><a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="images/quote4.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="images/quote4.png" title="large image" /></a></td> 
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
    <td><a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="images/quote5.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="images/quote5.png" title="large image" /></a></td>
    <td><a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="images/quote6.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="images/quote6.png" title="large image" /></a></td> 
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
    <td><a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="images/quote7.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="images/quote7.png" title="large image" /></a></td>
    <td><a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="images/quote8.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="images/quote8.png" title="large image" /></a></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: Which border? I don't see any.

Comment: Please add the link to your images as well.

Comment: I'm sorry stackoverflow won't let me attach an image because I do not have enough points. There is white lines in between the rows, which disrupts my image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the space between the rows is caused by the `a` tag inside the `td`. For default that tag has some value in the `line-height` in this case is more than the height of your image.

Try changing that

```
a.small {
   line-height:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi your code works well as for your requirement there is no white lines or space between the rows, if you see white lines then that may be a line from your image, then not nothing to deal with css

Answer (score 0):

[JsBin with a simplified example playground](http://jsbin.com/hobowo/1/edit?html,css,output)

Simply add:

```
#picture a img {
    border:0;
    vertical-align:middle; /* THIS LINE */
}
```